# How to open Visual Studio . Net in Excel 2003?

Tags: sql, download, excel-2003, visual-studio-2003

I am having trouble to understand the initial step of downloading SQL Data in Excel 2003.
Meaning that I have no clue how to open the VIsual Studio  in order to proceed with following steps.

Please refer to this link should I not be clear enough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192473%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Thank you all!

Comment: Visual Studio is a name of a development tool provided by Microsoft. do you have it installed in your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link:

> Prerequisites
>
> To complete this walkthrough, the following software and components
>   must be installed on the development computer:
>
> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio® .NET 2003 or Microsoft Visual Basic® .NET Standard 2003
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office System
> Microsoft Office Professional Edition 2003
> Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine (MSDE) 7.0 or 2000, with the Northwind sample database installed. This demonstration assumes that you've set up SQL Server/MSDE allowing
> ```
>
> access using integrated security.

Do you have all these tools installed?